# Trouble with running words through text files and counting them

Tags: file, python-3.x

Python 3+

This is the error i get
[image: This is the error i get]

This is my code
[image: This is my code]

I want the user to input some words, then the program should run each word through my two textfiles, if the word exists in any of them, I want the program to add +1 to the positive/negative count list.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have stumbled upon a Decoding error when trying to open one of the input files in the wordlist function. it is usually hard to determine the encoding used for a particular file. so you could :

1.Try opening the file with a different encoding such as ISO-8859-15,etc.

```
    def OpenFile():
        try:
            with open("My File.txt",mode="r",encoding="IS0-8859-15")
            #do process My File
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            print("Something went Wrong Try a different file encoding")
        else:
            #everything was okay, return the required
        finally:
            # clean up here
```

2. Look it modules that try and determine the correct encoding for the file such as the chardet module
   Install the 
   [chardet](http://chardet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) module :

```
sudo pip3 install chardet
```

you can run it at the command line with your file as the Argument to determine the encoding

```
cd /path/to/File/
chardetect My\ File.txt
```

this should return the likely encoding for the given file

3.You can use the chardet module inside your python code however this is recommended in a case where you will be opening a file you do not have access to e.g at a clients computer whom wants to open another specified file
and reopening the same file and redetecting the encoding will cause your program to be slow.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `positive_count` and `negative_count` should be integers and not lists. If you wish to count, adding 1 to the list isn't really what you're trying to accomplish.

Second of all, the `UnicodeDecodeError` is there because the encoding of the underlying file is not `utf-8`. Did you try `utf-16` or `utf-16-le`? In case you're using Windows, `utf-16-le` is probably the encoding used unless you're using code-points in which case guessing will be a nightmare.